# Possible alternatives to copy constructors

Tags: c++, libraries, pointers, smart-pointer, raii

In my C++ project I am relying on some libraries that do memory management for me. I make wrapper classes, for ease of use and memory safety, for example the class below. Note that this is a much simplified example, to demonstrate my problem.

```
#include <library>

class Wrapper {
private:
    lib_type* data;
public:
    Wrapper() : data(library_new()) {
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& orig) = delete;
    ~Wrapper() {
        library_free(data);
    }
    const lib_type* getData() const {
        return data;
    }
    /* ... */
    /* Lots of functions for using the wrapped object */
};
```

I needed to delete the copy constructor, because otherwise a copy going out of scope would invalidate the original object. Not being allowed to have copies makes the object very impractical to use - everywhere it is used I now need to hold a reference, and I need to manage the object centrally, which partially defeats the purpose of the wrapper class.

Possible solutions I have tried/thought of:

- **Copying the data.** This is normally not an option though, because it is either not allowed by the library or the data is huge.
- **Move constructors.** I tried solving the lack of a copy constructor by using a move constructor, but depending on the implementation, either this did not solve the problem or it became effectively a copy constructor, reintroducing the related problems.
- **Smart pointers.** Then I realized it might be solved by using smart pointers to the wrapper instead of references, as this removes the need to maintain a central copy.
- **Wrapping a smart pointer.** Or I could wrap a smart pointer to the data instead of a raw pointer. This makes the implementation of the wrapper a little bit more complicated, but also makes it easier to use, giving the classes using it a cleaner interface.

My attempt at the second smart pointer solution applied to the example above:

```
#include <library>

class Deleter {
public:
    void operator()(lib_type* p) const {
        library_free(p);
    }
};

class Wrapper {
private:
    shared_ptr<lib_type> data;
public:
    Wrapper() : data(library_new(), Deleter()) {
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& orig) : data(orig.data) {
    }
    ~Wrapper() {
    }
    const lib_type* getData() const {
        return *data;
    }
    /* ... */
    /* Lots of functions for using the wrapped object */
};
```

**Now for the concrete question:** is this a good solution? Or are there other, perhaps better solutions?

I am particularly worried about the getData implementation; whether I should return a copy of the shared pointer or a naked pointer and why.

Comment: It is generally a good solution. But you should be more specific (what exactly is `lib_type` ? what are its memory conventions?). Perhaps you need to use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: There are various cases, this was just an abstract example. The concrete example which led me to finally asking here is an image loader, so the pointer points to a large unsigned char array and the library provides me with the size of the array as well. Another example is an OpenGL shader program. Here there is no data present as it is only present on the GPU, but `glDeleteProgram` needs to be called when I am done with it. In this case I suppose only the other smart pointer solution is possible. I don't see how `unique_ptr` can be of help, because it still won't allow copies.

Comment: Do you need copies of the shader program? These things may be obvious to you, but they aren't to us, and you didn't really discuss your lifetime or sharing requirements in any detail.

Comment: @DavidHammen just a typo

Comment: @Useless yes, different renderers may use it, and with copies based on shared pointers, the program will be deleted when all renderers don't need it anymore, which seems to be the best RAII-strategy to me. Otherwise I would need to maintain a central instance, which makes it unclear when to destroy it.

Comment: I changed the title of your question, because the original title had no information in it.  If the new title doesn't accurately reflect the content of your question, feel free to change it to something more suitable, but please don't just put your Google search terms there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these implementations are reasonable and a generally good solution. **Adding an appropriate move constructor and move assignment may help deal with your copy concerns** - the default should be appropriate with the shared wrapper.

Some may argue (or advise) that you do not need to wrap the Standard Library facilities that you use here; whilst this is true, the semantics of the `getData()` function may be quite specific for your target code - **using the library facility or wrapping it is really a design tradeoff**.

You may need *a few tweaks on the assignment operators*; and possibly be more explicit on the other special member functions (I would favour this here - it makes the intent of the code clearer). By way of example;

```
#include <library>

class UniqueWrapper {
private:
    lib_type* data;
public:
    UniqueWrapper() : data(library_new()) {}
    UniqueWrapper(const UniqueWrapper&) = delete;
    UniqueWrapper& operator=(const UniqueWrapper&) = delete;
    UniqueWrapper(UniqueWrapper&&) = delete;
    UniqueWrapper& operator=(UniqueWrapper&&) = delete;

    ~UniqueWrapper() {
        library_free(data);
    }
    const lib_type* getData() const {
        return data;
    }
};
```

And as a shared wrapper;

```
#include <library>

class Deleter {
public:
    void operator()(lib_type* p) const {
        library_free(p);
    }
};

class SharedWrapper {
private:
    shared_ptr<lib_type> data;
public:
    SharedWrapper() : data(library_new(), Deleter()) {}

    SharedWrapper(const SharedWrapper& orig) = default;
    SharedWrapper& operator=(const SharedWrapper& orig) = default;
    SharedWrapper(SharedWrapper&& orig) = default;
    SharedWrapper& operator=(SharedWrapper&& orig) = default;

    ~SharedWrapper() = default;

    const lib_type* getData() const {
        return data.get(); // a reference return could also be used.
    }
    const lib_type& getDataAlt() const {
        // alternative for a reference
        return *data;
    }
};
```

On your last question;

> I am particularly worried about the getData implementation; whether I should return a copy of the shared pointer or a naked pointer and why?

When you expose some of the internals of an object, you give up some control over how that data is used - essentially this is not a bad thing, you just need to bear that in mind.

Having said that, there are ways you can make the code easy to use properly and hard to use incorrectly. Returning a `const` in this case would probably be advised, since the method is `const` - it is saying to the client of your code, don't change it. If changes are to be allowed, then a non-`const` version is also required.

The wrapper class you have is there to manage the resource, so I would advise returning a reference (hence for observation) over a pointer; a pointer can be a `nullptr` so if there is an "optional" nature to the value, a `nullptr` pointer can be used to indicate that.

If the shared and const-ness of the return type is to be maintained, David Hammen's solution of `shared_ptr<const lib_type>` is neat.

Comment: Wouldn't `getData()` return a `lib_type` in the second example (shared wrapper)? Dereferencing the shared_ptr would return the data, not a pointer. Maybe you meant `data.get()`?

Comment: @LorToso. Yes, I copied that code over, I'll get that fixed. Thanks for that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your second paragraph ("Some may argue..."). If I see it correctly the only changes other than the fix by LorToso you made were explicitly adding the default special members. Why is it better to do this explicitly?

Comment: @Oebele. I mean "same may say...", the custom class may not be needed as it is a thin wrapper over `std::shared_ptr`. It is a personal preference, but given the RAII nature of the class I favour being explicit in the class definition of what is defined and what is deleted. I think that is makes the RAII class usage and intent clearer. C++ has rules on the special members, so it is not explicitly needed (and can be removed as personal preference).

Comment: @Oebele. There is not much that needs to change - I think you have a good solution. These are merely minor tweaks.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `shared_ptr` directly, with your custom deleter. Maybe typedef it if you prefer.

This way you get correct move & copy constructors and assignment operators *with no typing*. You also get `weak_ptr` for free, if you want it.

Unless your code will add some actual functionality - or at least an interface compatible with some external requirement you didn't mention - the best thing you can possibly do is just not write it in the first place.

Look at Niall's `SharedWrapper` for a good example: unless you *need* that `getData` signature, it's a lot of code for no actual benefit. (This isn't a criticism: that was clearly written on the assumption that you *do* need the `getData` signature).

Comment: In many cases there is a bit more to it than in the example. Additionally, I am okay with adding this amount of code, if that improves the ease-of-use and readability of the rest of the code.

Comment: If you think `shared_ptr` is hard to use and hinders readability ... I strongly suggest you just get more familiar with `shared_ptr` and use it anyway, tbh. Unless you mean there's a bit more to your wrapper? Either way, I'd recommend `shared_ptr` as the default, and write your own wrapper only if you have some strong reason.

Comment: The main reason is because there is more to the wrapper. With readability I meant, for example, that a member of the type `Image` makes it intent a lot clearer than a member of the type `shared_ptr<unsigned char>` or `unsigned char*`. I believe this is called self-documentation. But again, main reason is that there is more to the class.

Comment: I see. Well, since I can't comment on code I can't see, I still don't have any reason to prefer the wrapper over `unique_ptr` (and typedef is probably sufficient for documentation purposes). My general approach is that writing a custom wrapper is bad practice unless it does something, and I don't know what, if anything, yours does.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer addresses the final part of the question. The bulk of the question has already been nicely addressed in Niall's answer.

> I am particularly worried about the getData implementation; whether I should return a copy of the shared pointer or a naked pointer and why.

Suppose some code calls `getData()` and saves that pointer in some persistent object, and that the last remaining `Wrapper` object that references this pointer goes out of scope before this persistent object does. That persistent object now contains an invalid pointer.

To solve this problem, it would be much better to return the shared pointer. This runs into another problem, which is that your `getData()` currently returns a pointer to const lib_type. Returning a `const shared_ptr<lib_type>` will not do what you want, for two reasons. One is that this makes it possible for the caller of `getData()` to modify the data, something you don't want to happen. The other is that `const` is meaningless; it's like returning a `const int`. The compiler ignores that `const`. Instead, use

```
shared_ptr<const lib_type> getData() const {
    return data;
}
```

The above takes advantage of the fact that a `shared_ptr<some_type>` automatically converts to a `shared_ptr<const some_type>`. The reverse (converting a `shared_ptr<const some_type>` to a `shared_ptr<some_type>`) is illegal (which is presumably the behavior you want).

One last remark: Those type names can get long and clunky. Presumably you are using `std::shared_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr`, and `lib_type` is presumably something like `some_namespace::AMoreDescriptiveNameThanLibType`. To specify the type of the value received from a call to `getData`, a user of your code would have to write

```
std::shared_ptr<const some_namespace::AMoreDescriptiveNameThanLibType> data =
    wrapper.getData();
```

One way around this is to use `auto`:

```
    auto data = wrapper.getData();
```

Another option is to provide some type definitions (or some type aliases) in your definition of `Wrapper`:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<lib_type> dataT;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const lib_type> const_dataT;
    // Rest of code elided
};
```

Then your users only have to type

```
Wrapper::const_dataT data = wrapper.getData();
```

Comment: I like the return type here - very neat.

Comment: What, effectively, does it mean if a `shared_ptr` is `const`? The contents cannot be changed, but that does not matter, because it is a copy, right? Does it also mean it can't be copied, as that changes the reference count? I only see downsides of doing that. `const`ing the contents is nice though.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` which has a template argument of `const lib_type` means that this smart pointer allows you to access an instance `lib_type` that is const-qualified (either by pointer or by reference), meaning that you cannot write to its public fields or call its non-const-qualified methods.

Comment: @rwong - The `const` that preceded `shared_ptr<const lib_type>` was indeed a typo. Thanks for catching it; I fixed it.

Comment: @DavidHammen so, the first `const` in your example should be removed? If so could you please update your answer to reflect that?

Comment: @Oebele - I did update my answer, quite a few minutes ago. Then I saw that I hadn't pushed the commit button.

Comment: Turns out this solution is not applicable in the current case, but I am sure I will use it in an other wrapper. Thanks!